# pgAdmin III : No servers showing up

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've followed many online tutorials on how to install pgAdmin correctly, I've installed and uninstalled it multiple times but whenever install it. It shows Server Groups without any servers in it.

Then when I try and register a new server using `localhost` for both name and host I get this error:

```
server doesn't listen
```

Searched for days trying to find a solution for this, any ideas?[image]

Comment: Did you install Postgresql **server**?

Comment: I did exactly what he did in the tutorial. downloaded postgresql and it just doesn't show a server for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reinstalled program and saved it to directory C:\ instead of C:\program_Files

Answer (score 20):

Happened with me as well, when I started `pgadmin3` for the first time, I was expecting it to ask for the password which I provided during but it didnt ask and then didnt display any servers.
Anyways, you can create a server yourself.
If your server is on the same machine,

provide a name: test
provide server: localhost 
provide a port number : 5432 (default port) 
provider a username: postgres (default user, you can change later in login roles)
password: provide something

Restart if required, and it will then show you a
database with `postgres` (default db),
`tablespace`, and `login roles` under your server, and you should be good to go .

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. I wasn't sure what "name" would refer to, e.g. database name, server name, my name etc. It looks like it is the server name, and just providing this data to create a "server" (whatever that really is - the server was already running) worked fine.

Comment: My dialog requires both host and service name, host was trying localhost or the machine name, can't seem to get this working. No idea what the Service Name is.

Answer (score 5):

When I did this invalid password message appeared. So I had to change postgres user password:
In the terminal window:

1. Switch to the postgres account on the server by typing:

sudo -i -u postgres

2. Now I can access a Postgres prompt immediately by:

psql

3. Change the postgres user password:

ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'newpass';

Answer (score 4):

First Create a Server with the following credential-

```
Host Name/address : localhost
Port : 5432
Maintenance database : postgres

Username : postgres
Password : *Your_Password*
```

**Note** : *Before Creating the Server first start the postgresql server*